# Rails deployment to Amazon EC2 - No space left on device

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am deploying my app to Amazon EC2 with using Capistrano and I just see the error message

```
No space left on device
```

while the deployment process. I am not aware that I would store whatever on Amazon EC2 except the application itself. All files are stored on Amazon S3.

How to deal with this issue?

**EDIT:** 
The output of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.9G  7.4G   99M  99% /
udev            288M  8.0K  288M   1% /dev
tmpfs           119M  180K  118M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            296M     0  296M   0% /run/shm
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Capistrano doesn't remove old release per default.

I suggest to add this to your `config/deploy.rb`:

```
set :keep_releases, 5

after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup"
```

That tells Capistrano to keep only the last 5 releases (might be important if you need to rollback) and to delete older releases when the deploy of a new version was successful.

Or you can remove older releases manually by calling:

```
cap deploy:cleanup -s keep_releases=5
```